# Using nested IF/AND statements in Sheets in a single cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm trying to create a formula that looks at a cell and determines what range the cell is between and then fills another cell with a specific value depending on the target cell's value. This is the formula I've created:

```
=IF(AND(C4>0,C4<5,1,IF(AND(C4>=5,C4<8,2,IF(C4>=8,3)))))
```

Where `C4` is the number of hours an employee worked in one day. I'm trying to determine if they were eligible for 1, 2 or 3 10 minute breaks and assign that value to `C6`.

What I'm getting is this message:

Error

> Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments,
>   but got 1 arguments.

How do I fix this?

Comment: An `AND` joins the two statements on either side of it together, and you've not got any statement to the left of your `AND`. I'm not too familiar with Google Spreadsheets, but you may be looking for something like `=IF (C4 > 0, C4 < 5,1) AND (C4 >= 5, C4 < 8,2, C4 >= 8,3)`.

Answer (score 0):

IF() function should have two parameters and optionally a third one.

IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)

Answer (score 0):

The `IF` statement works as follows:
`IF(logic_test, value_if true, value_if_false)`

Your first `IF` statement has only the logic_test part (the output of `AND`). so you have to provide the other parameters.